SearchQuery using datetimepicker delayed by one action
Everytime i click to search orders based on the date, it doesnt keep track of my current selectedDate, it keeps track of my previous one. Example: If i click 20 May, 21 May, 24 May, by the time i choose 24 May, it would be on 21 May, hence delayed by one action. I don't understand how it works so any help would be appreciated. I need the codes and explanations
//API
router.get("/orders", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { date } = req.query;
    let orders;

    if (date) {
      orders = await OrdersModel.findAll({
        where: { orderDate: date },
      });
    } else {
      // If no date parameter is provided, fetch all orders
      orders = await OrdersModel.findAll();
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      data: orders,
      metadata: date ? `Show Orders for ${date}` : "Show All Orders",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: "An error occurred while fetching the orders",
    });
  }
});

//FrontEnd
const fetchOrders = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://192.168.1.2:3000/users/orders?date=${selectedDate
          .toISOString()
          .slice(0, 10)}`,
      )
      .then(res => {
        setOrders(res.data.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching orders:', error);
      });
  };

const handleDateChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    if (selectedDate) {
      hideDatePickerModal();
      const currentDate = selectedDate;
      setSelectedDate(currentDate);
      fetchOrders(currentDate); // Update orders based on selected date
    }
  };

{showDatePicker && (
        <DateTimePicker
          testID="dateTimePicker"
          value={selectedDate}
          mode="date"
          is24Hour={true}
          display="default"
          onChange={handleDateChange}
        />
      )}

I've tried asking GPT and Blackbox but to no avail
